Google Cloud Storage Image Upload not working in Flutter Web App
I have a Flutter Web App that lets me upload an image to Google Cloud storage using Firebase.
It works fine in Debug mode on Flutter and even on "flutter run --release". However when I build the app using "flutter build web" and then host it locally using a python web server or even when I host it using Firebase Hosting directly, when I want to upload the picture I just get this unidentifiable error:
main.dart.js:7666 Uncaught
at Object.c (localhost/main.dart.js:5261:19)
at localhost/main.dart.js:49953:20
at aqZ.a (localhost/main.dart.js:6608:63)
at aqZ.$2 (localhost/main.dart.js:41745:14)
at apY.$1 (localhost/main.dart.js:41739:21)
at anQ.aoc (localhost/main.dart.js:42737:34)
at anQ.v5 (localhost/main.dart.js:42740:13)
at akK.$0 (localhost/main.dart.js:42189:11)
at Object.vq (localhost/main.dart.js:6747:40)
at aa.n0 (localhost/main.dart.js:42124:3)

I tried e.g.

Declaring my Storage bucket in firebase.json
changing the CORS policy
setting read write permissions to always true in Cloud Storage

Here are the main code snippets:
Future<void> pickImage() async {
    Uint8List? result = await ImagePickerWeb.getImageAsBytes();

    if (result != null) {
      setState(() {
        _imageBytes = result;
      });
    }
  }

  Future<String> uploadImageToFirebase(Uint8List imageBytes) async {
    try {
      FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.instanceFor(
          bucket: "gs://bucket-url-here");

      String filePath = 'images/${DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch}.png';
      Reference ref = storage.ref().child(filePath);

      UploadTask uploadTask =
          ref.putData(imageBytes, SettableMetadata(contentType: 'image/png'));

      await uploadTask;

      String downloadURL = await ref.getDownloadURL();
      return downloadURL;
    } on FirebaseException catch (e) {
      print("FirebaseException: ${e.message}");
      setState(() {
        errormessage = e.message!;
      });
      return Future.error("Firebase error: ${e.code}");
    } catch (e) {
      print("General Exception: $e");
      setState(() {
        errormessage = e.toString();
      });
      return Future.error("An error occurred: $e");
    }
  }

